# Flux of a hemisphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

I have been asked to compute the flux through a hemisphere radius 2 centred at the origin oriented downward with 
$$
\overrightarrow{F}=(y,-x,2z)
$$
I have worked out that 
$$
\hat{n}=-\frac{(x,y,z)}{2}
$$ 
and in spherical co-ordinates, 
$$
dS=4\sin(\gamma)d\gamma d\theta.
$$ 
So the flux is given by 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-2\cos(\gamma)4\sin(\gamma)d\gamma d\theta.
$$

My question is, do I also need to calculate the flux through the bottom of the hemisphere, namely the disk $x^{2}+y^2=4$ on the $xy$ plane, or is this included in the integral above?

Comment: It's included *neither* in the question nor in the integral you wrote.

Comment: @TedShifrin how do you mean? Surely as the bottom part of the hemisphere is part of the surface it should be included in some part of the calculation?

Comment: Only if the instructions say to include the disk at the bottom of the hemisphere.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying